# How to retrieve mongo's documents limited by nested property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Imagine the following data structure:

```
[
   {
     "_id": ...,
     "title": "Post #1",
     "date": "2019-01-01"
     "comments": [
         {
             "_id": ...,
             "text": "Comment #1 on #1",
             "date": "2019-01-01"
         }
     ]
   },
   {
    "_id": ...,
    "title": "Post #2",
    "date": "2019-02-01"
    "comments": [
        {
            "_id": ...,
            "text": "Comment #1 on #2",
            "date": "2019-02-01" // too old
        },
        {
            "_id": ...,
            "text": "Comment #2 on #2",
            "date": "2019-02-10"
        },
        {
            "_id": ...,
            "text": "Comment #3 on #2",
            "date": "2019-02-20"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ...,
    "title": "Post #3",
    "date": "2019-02-12"
    "comments": [
        {
            "_id": ...,
            "text": "Comment #1 on #3",
            "date": "2019-02-15"
        }
    ]
  },

   {
     "_id": ...,
     "title": "Post #4",
     "date": "2019-03-01"
     "comments": [] // none
   }
]
```

I'd like to show the 3 latest comments with its posts.

It should be:

- Comment #1 on #3
- Comment #3 on #2
- Comment #2 on #2

The output should be something like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ...,
    "title": "Post #3",
    "date": "2019-02-12"
    "comments": [
        {
            "_id": ...,
            "text": "Comment #1 on #3",
            "date": "2019-02-15"
        }
    ]
  },
   {
    "_id": ...,
    "title": "Post #2",
    "date": "2019-02-01"
    "comments": [
        {
            "_id": ...,
            "text": "Comment #3 on #2",
            "date": "2019-02-20"
        },
        {
            "_id": ...,
            "text": "Comment #2 on #2",
            "date": "2019-02-10"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is it possible to execute such search on Mongo?
The important thing to note is: the "limit" is 3, but it returned 2 documents/posts with 3 comments in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([{
    $unwind : "$comments"
},{
    $sort : {"date" : 1, "comments.date" : 1}
},{
    $limit : 3
},{
    $group :{
        _id : "$_id",
        title : {$first : "$title"},
        date : {$first : "$date"},
        comments : {$push : "$comments"},
    }
}])
```

Comment: 1: "unknown group operator '$post'". Then I tried "post" instead

2: The field 'comments' must be an accumulator object

Comment: It should be `push`, instead of `post`. I have updated my answer, kindly check.

Comment: Yes, it works. I just had to fix the sorting: `$sort : {"comments.date" : -1}`